# How to draw a line with elevation representation in WorldWind

Tags: javafx, line, worldwind

I want to draw a line on the globe with elevation representation, something like this :

[image: Elevation representation sketch]

I know I can use polyline to represent a line, but how can fill the space below the line ?

Comment: Does the globe make a difference here, I mean can it be a plain as well? Should be the filled area be segmented?

Comment: Absolutly no need of segmentation, the goal is just to represent the elevation of the line

Comment: Is this really related to javafx ?

Comment: Well I use a worldwind panel in a javafx application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a path to draw the line. The setOutlineMaterial will draw a "curtain" similar to what you want.

```
Path path = new Path(pathPositions); //Arraylist of positions
final BasicShapeAttributes attrs = new BasicShapeAttributes();
attrs.setInteriorOpacity(0.25);
attrs.setInteriorMaterial(Material.BLACK);
attrs.setOutlineMaterial(new Material(color));
attrs.setOutlineWidth(width);
path.setAttributes(attrs);
path.setDrawVerticals(true);
path.setAltitudeMode(WorldWind.ABSOLUTE);
```

look at [`Path`](http://builds.worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/worldwind-releases/1.2/docs/api/gov/nasa/worldwind/render/AbstractShape.html#setAltitudeMode(int)) altitude mode how you want it follow the ground.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a polygon, just give it points with the same latitude and longitude but different elevations:

```
ArrayList<Position> pathPositions = new ArrayList<Position>();
pathPositions.add(Position.fromDegrees(28, -106, 3e4));
pathPositions.add(Position.fromDegrees(28, -106, 3e0));
pathPositions.add(Position.fromDegrees(35, -107, 9e0));
pathPositions.add(Position.fromDegrees(35, -107, 9e4));
pathPositions.add(Position.fromDegrees(28, -106, 3e4));
Polygon pgon = new Polygon(pathPositions);
```

Comment: And use setExtrude also to draw the elevation.